# Ajax Tiles: HTML source present, but some tiles not rendered

Tags: ajax, spring-webflow, spring-js

**The Problem**

I am really stuck on this. Expert help would be very much appreciated.

I am using webflow2/spring4?thymeleaf/tiles2.

When I make an ajax request, only some tiles are rendered visible but all tiles are "there" when I look at the html source. I am also at a loss as to why some are rendered visible and some not.

I am unable to identify a distinct difference between those rendered and those not rendered.

Forgive the screenshots, but it helps show the problem.

*This is what the page should look like:*
[image]

*This is what is rendered after the ajax call*
[image]

Relevant code is as follows:

**Tiles Config**

```html
<definition name="standard2r1ct2cb" template="/layouts/standard2r1ct2cb" templateType="thymeleaf">
  <put-attribute name="header" value="/tiles/headerTile :: mainHead" type="thymeleaf" cascade="true" />
  <put-attribute name="banner" value="/tiles/bannerTile :: mainBanner" type="thymeleaf" cascade="true" />
  <put-attribute name="pageTitleTile" value="/tiles/pageTitleTile :: pageTitleTile_hello" type="thymeleaf" cascade="true" />
  <put-attribute name="s1" value="/tiles/blank :: blank" type="thymeleaf" cascade="true" />
  <put-attribute name="s2" value="/tiles/blank :: blank" type="thymeleaf" cascade="true"  />
  <put-attribute name="s3" value="/tiles/blank :: blank" type="thymeleaf" cascade="true" />
  <put-attribute name="s4" value="/tiles/blank :: blank" type="thymeleaf" cascade="true" />
  <put-attribute name="s5" value="/tiles/blank :: blank" type="thymeleaf" cascade="true" />
  <put-attribute name="s6" value="/tiles/blank :: blank" type="thymeleaf" cascade="true" />
  <put-attribute name="s7" value="/tiles/blank :: blank" type="thymeleaf" cascade="true" />
  <put-attribute name="s8" value="/tiles/blank :: blank" type="thymeleaf" cascade="true" />
 </definition>


 
 
 
 
 <definition name="xzcreatetesttype" extends="standard2r1ct2cb" templateType="thymeleaf">
  <put-attribute name="pageTitleTile" value="/tiles/pageTitleTile :: pageTitleTile_newtt" type="thymeleaf" cascade="true" />
  <put-attribute name="s1" value="/ajaxTiles/newTestTypeAjaxFragment :: s1"  type="thymeleaf" cascade="true"/>
  <put-attribute name="s2" value="/ajaxTiles/selectedTestUnitTypesAjaxFragment"  type="thymeleaf" cascade="true" />
  <put-attribute name="s4" value="/ajaxTiles/addTutAjaxFragment"  type="thymeleaf" cascade="true"/>
  <put-attribute name="s6" value="/tiles/pageTitleTile :: pageTitleTile_newtut"  type="thymeleaf" cascade="true"/>
  <put-attribute name="s7" value="/tiles/xzcreatetestunittypeTiles :: selectedTucets"  type="thymeleaf" cascade="true"/>
  <put-attribute name="s8" value="/tiles/xzcreatetestunittypeTiles :: tucetsList"  type="thymeleaf" cascade="true"/>
  
 </definition>
```

None of the s1 thru s8 tiles are rendered except s4 which initiated the ajax call.

**Template**
(tiles:include and tiles:replace don't seem to make a difference)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
 xmlns:tiles="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
 xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">

<head tiles:include="header"></head>
<body>
 <div tiles:include="banner"></div> 
 <TABLE id="bodyMainTable">
  <TR>
   <div tiles:include="pageTitleTile">s1</div>
  </TR>
  <TR>
   <TD id="bodyMainCellBody" colspan="2"><br /> <br /> <br />
    <TABLE id="bodyInnerTable">
     <TR>
      <TD colspan="2" id="bodyMainCellBody" >

       <div tiles:replace="s1">s1</div>
       <div tiles:replace="s2">s2</div>
      </TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD id="bodyMainCellBody" style="width:50%">
       <div tiles:replace="s3">s3</div>
       <div tiles:replace="s4">s4</div>
       <div tiles:include="s5">s5</div>
      </TD>
      <TD id="bodyMainCellBody" style="width:50%">
          <div tiles:include="s6">s3</div>
       <div tiles:include="s7">s4</div>
       <div tiles:include="s8">s5</div></TD>
     </TR>
..........
```

**webflow**

```html
<view-state id="xzcreatetesttype">
  <transition on="addtut">
   <evaluate
    expression="testTypeViewService.addTestUnitTypeToTestType(flowScope.vwNewTestType,flowRequestContext)"
    result="flowScope.vwNewTestType" />
    
   <render fragments="s2,s4" />
  </transition>
  
..........
```

**Ajax Call**

```html
<table id="bodyInnerTable"
 style="border: 1px solid #007589; width: 100%; vertical-align: top">
 <tr>
  <td id="bodyMainCellHead" colspan="2" th:text="#{label.availabletuts}">Name</td>

 </tr>
 
 <!-- Iterate through the children (retrieved from db and held in bean as TreeMap) 
 Each <a> tag must have a unique th:id. 
 
 -->
 <tr th:each="tut : ${vwNewTestType.tutMap}" th:if="${vwNewTestType.tutMap.size() > 0}">
  <td><a th:id="${tut.value}" name="addtutname"
   th:href="@{'~' + ${flowExecutionUrl}(_eventId=addtut, tutid=${tut.value},tutname=${tut.key})}">Add</a></td>
  <td th:text="${tut.key}">id</td>
 </tr>
</table>


<!-- dojo .forEach will then allow for identification of which element  is clicked and the webflow transition on=""addtut" is called-->

<script type="text/javascript">
 
 
 dojo.query("a[name=addtutname]").forEach(function(element) 
   {
       Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
           elementId: element.id,
           event: "onclick"
           //params: {  fragments:"s2,s4"}
       }))
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is the "it works now" answer, but it is not the full explanation. 
An expert explanation would be greatly appreciated.

The only thing that the non-displaying tiles had in common was that they were all part of the inner table.

I stripped out the inner table from the template and now it works.

I do not understand why this fixed the problem.
I am also unsure if the problem is with tiles, thymeleaf or webflow.